# NSFetchedResultsController - parent and grandparent as section title

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to create a sectioned `TableView`. My data model looks like as:

City <--->> District <--->> Street

My TableView should look like this:

```
,------------,
| City 1     |    --- Section 0
`------------´

,------------,
| District 1 |    --- Section 1
`------------´
| Street 1   |    --- Row 0
`------------´
| Street 2   |    --- Row 1
`------------´

,------------,
| District 2 |    --- Section 2
`------------´
| Street A   |    --- Row 0
`------------´
| Street B   |    --- Row 1
`------------´

,------------,
| City 2     |   --- Section 3
`------------´
```

The problem is, if I define a sectionNameKeyPath on my `FetchedResultsController`, I only get the names of the districts or the names of the cities but not both.
Is this even possible?

That's my `FetchedResultsController` so far:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResults != nil) {
        return _fetchedResults;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Street" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"toDistrict.toCity.toUser.userId = %@",currentUser.userId];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortCities = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"toDistrict.toCity.name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDistricts = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"toDistrict.name" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortStreets = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortCities, sortDistricts, sortStreets, nil]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"toDistrict.toCity.name" cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResults = theFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResults.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResults;

}
```

What do I need to change in order to achieve the above look of the TableView? Or am I completely wrong and need a different structure?

Any hints and help would be appreciated.

Comment: The hierarchy of that table view is difficult to understand. Is section 0 grouping section 1 and section 2 in you drawing above? That is not really possible with UITableView. You can only have 2 levels; section heading and rows for the section heading. You will need to add some voodoo to achieve what you desire, but I won't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following: fetch the `Street` entity and use the relationship to the `District` entity as the `sectionNameKeyPath` when creating the fetched results controller. You need to have a clear way of ordering the districts, and a district should know its position in this hierarchy when queried.

From your diagram it is clear that there is no space between the city and district headers. Thus, you could just return a larger, special header that combines the two. Each district has to know it is the first in the city and inform the table view `datasource` methods to add the additional information above.

Note that you will have to account for this in both `viewForHeaderInSection:` and `heightForHeaderInSection:`.

Comment: I really like that idea and tried to realize it. Unfortunately, I just get a sorting by district and street name and not by city name. This is messing up my tableview structure. It's important for me to have the above mentioned structure.

Comment: You can also fetch the districts without section headings, sort by country, and use `district.streets` in your datasource for the rows under a section.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is not possible with a NSFetchedResultsController as you pointed out the sectionNameKeyPath does limit you. At the same time as a user I'm pretty sure I would prefer to have a first list of city that once selected push another view controller that contain the district and again when selected present the streets. it will allows your app to contain more data without losing your users into one big unending lists.

Comment: You're right but that's the design that was given to me and I'm not allowed to use another one. So I need to find a way to deal with it.